Why is this code which should print the pascal's triangle not working?
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void solve(vector<vector<long long>> &answer, vector<long long> first, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    vector<long long> second;
    for (int i = -1; i < first.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == -1)
        {
            second.push_back(first[0]);
            continue;
        }
        if (i == first.size() - 1)
        {
            second.push_back(first.back());
            continue;
        }
        long long sum = first[i] + first[i + 1];
        second.push_back(sum);
    }
    answer.push_back(second);
    solve(answer, second, n - 1);
}
vector<vector<long long int>> printPascal(int n)
{
    vector<vector<long long>> answer;
    vector<long long> first;
    first.push_back(1);
    answer.push_back(first);
    solve(answer, first, n - 1);
    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    vector<vector<long long>> answer = printPascal(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < answer[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << answer[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


I tried solving the issue with AI, but it just says that my approach is not good and gives me a new better code. I don't want a better code. This approach was made by me and I just want to know why this is not working.
When I asked AI to dry run my code, it gave the correct answer, but it does not give correct answer in vs code or the platform on which I am solving it (code 360). I know the platform is disappointing, but the code should work as expected in other environments.

A few things: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? Only tag the programming language you're actually writing your code in, C and C++ are very different. And the dsa tag is for DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) and you should NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions!

As for your problem, you need to learn how to debug your code. For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend you try to figure out the program using pen and paper first. And implement it just one or two lines at a time, building with extra warnings and testing between each line or two.

Please elaborate "it does not work".

And regarding AI, it can't really help you unless you're willing to spend some time to refine both your code and your prompts in a continuous chat with it. And know that the code it will give you could be deeply flawed in unknown ways, because the AI doesn't really know anything, it just copy-paste snippets together that it could have learned from very bad sources. It's not really intelligent as such. It requires you to be already well-experienced with programming to be helpful.

OT: Why have if (i == -1) .... inside the loop. Just do it before the loop

There are many other problems in your code as well, that could leads to bad run-time behavior or even crashes. Whatever source you use to learn C++ it doesn't to a very good job. Please invest in some good books to learn properly. Even if they might be expensive, they will be worth it in the long run, it's good investment if you're serious about learning C++.

OT: Why have if (i == first.size() - 1) ... inside the loop.

Competitive coding is not a good way to learn C++, check learncpp.com. Learn how to use C++ reference and then check the C++ core guidelines all of these should IMO be done before you ever touch competitive coding. If you start with that first you only will learn bad habits that will not help you later.

@PaulH Your edit proposal is not thorough enough. For an edit that earns you reputation you are expected to at least not skip obvious other improvements.

The error is here
for (int i = -1; i < first.size(); i++)

The expression i < first.size() will always evaluates to false because the return value from vector::size is unsigned. This is a case where C++ and regular math don't agree, so it's an easy mistake to make.
When comparing a signed value to an unsigned value C++ first converts the signed value to unsigned. In the case of -1 this results in the largest possible unsigned value, and this means that i < first.size() is always false.
Here's one way to fix this problem (this is untested)
vector<long long> second;
second.push_back(first[0]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < first.size(); i++)
{
    if (i + 1 == first.size())
    {
        second.push_back(first.back());
        continue;
    }
    ...

In general be very careful about using signed types (e.g. int) for vector indexes, prefer size_t instead. Also be careful about using - on unsigned values because of potential overflow problems. That's why I replaced i == first.size() - 1 with i + 1 == first.size() in the code above.

The if (i + 1 == first.size()) could be moved outside of the loop as well.

Agreed, place second.push_back(first.back()); after the for loop, and replace for (size_t i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) with for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < first.size(); i++)

And the for loops in main have the same problem
